# Copy a batch file that's running

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file. When I run it i want it to clone itself to the program files.

It can't find anything so far.

It needs to check if the folder 'toolset' exist. If not copy itself to C:/program fiels/toolset/*filename*.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Your title says `move` the file but you describe `copying` the file.  Which is it?  In either case you will strike a UAC prompt because it requires admin permissions.

Comment: Its copying. Sorry my bad. I already found something that checks the admin things. It can only do it when the use click on the richt button > Run as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do as you ask:

```
@echo off
if not exist "%programfiles%\toolset\" (
    md "%programfiles%\toolset\"
    copy "%~f0" "%programfiles%\toolset\"
)
```